# Reading tables using OleDBConnection

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbcommand

First off, i'm new to VB and this is my first project using OleDBConnection.

ok, so i'm trying to the most simple thing using oleDbConnection (i assume). I just want to read data from a table in the Access DB and display that information to dropboxes (or anything) in my winForm.

```
Public Class QueManger
Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection
Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
Dim dbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source = \\atrts10\F:\Applications\ATRTaxCert\Development\mtaylor\TaxCert_be_test.accdb"
Dim dtMain As DataTable

Private Sub QueManger_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    StatusName()
End Sub

Private Sub StatusName()
    Dim taxconn As OleDbConnection
    Try

        taxconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\atrts10\F:\Applications\ATRTaxCert\Development\mtaylor\TaxCert_be_test.accdb")
        Dim taxcmd As OleDbCommand = taxconn.CreateCommand
        taxcmd.CommandText = "SELECT StatusName FROM Status ORDER BY StatusName"
        Dim rdr2 As OleDbDataReader
        If taxconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            taxconn.Open()
        End If
        rdr2 = taxcmd.ExecuteReader

        'boxStatus.Items.Add("All")
        While rdr2.Read()
            boxClient.Items.Add(rdr2.Item("StatusName"))
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        taxconn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The error comes when it tries to run the "taxconn.Open()" function.

The error says "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\atrts10\F:\Applications\ATRTaxCert\Development\mtaylor\TaxCert_be_test.accdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data."

any thoughts?

Comment: You probably have the file open in MS Access.  I believe that it isn't generally an issue unless you currently have the design window open in Access for a table or something.

Comment: That's the thing. I thought that was the problem. I was trying to work on this code at work while people were using the DB, so i decide to make a copy of the DB just for my development and it is still bringing the error up. I'm the ONLY one that even knows about this version of the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to close the opened table first in access if you are editing them, and try to add "@" before the string to use your path.
then try to use this connection string;

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + yourDataBasePath + ";Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Comment: Don't confuse C# with VB.NET :)

Comment: oups :p i guess its too late hour working for me :p sorry guys

Comment: Yep, i knew it was C# but i still tried. With no luck of course. And like i've said, i'm the only one that knows about this version of the DB - so i know no one else is using it.